# ENV in docker file not getting replaced

Tags: python, docker, containers

I have a very simple docker file

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV CODEPATH=default_value
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["/usr/src/app/${CODEPATH}"]
```

Here is my container command

```
docker run -e TOKEN="subfolder/testmypython.py"  --name mycontainer -v /opt/testuser/pythoncode/:/usr/src/app/  -t -d  python-image:latest
```

when I see container logs it shows

python3: can't open file '/usr/src/app/${TOKEN}': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: CMD does not do env variable substitution. That's done by the shell.

Comment: env name CODEPATH but your setting TOKEN as env?
Please try  doker run -e CODEPATH="subfolder/testmypython.py"  --name mycontainer -v /opt/testuser/pythoncode/:/usr/src/app/  -t -d  python-image:latest

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want to do is override the default path to the python file which is run when you launch the container. Rather than passing this option in as an environment variable, you can just pass the path to the file as an argument to docker run, which is the purpose of [CMD in your dockerfile](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-cmd-vs-entrypoint#:%7E:text=CMD%20is%20an%20instruction%20that,container%20with%20a%20specific%20executable.). What you set as the CMD option is the default, which users of your image can easily override by passing an argument to the docker run command.

```
doker run --name mycontainer -v /opt/testuser/pythoncode/:/usr/src/app/ -t -d python-image:latest "subfolder/testmypython.py"
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variable name `CODEPATH` but your setting `TOKEN` as Environment variable.
could you please try setting CODEPATH as env in following way

```
doker run -e CODEPATH="subfolder/testmypython.py" --name mycontainer -v /opt/testuser/pythoncode/:/usr/src/app/ -t -d python-image:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you've split `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` doesn't make sense, and it makes it impossible to do variable expansion here.  You should combine the two parts together into a single `CMD`, and then use the shell form to run it:

```sh
# no ENTRYPOINT
CMD python3 /usr/src/app/${CODEPATH}
```

(Having done this, better still is to use the approach in [@allan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66776237/10008173) and directly `docker run python-image python3 other-script-name.py`.)

The Dockerfile syntax doesn't allow [environment expansion](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) in `RUN`, `ENTRYPOINT`, or `CMD` commands.  Instead, these commands have two forms.
[Exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) requires you to format the command as a JSON array, and doesn't do any processing on what you give it; it runs the command with an exact set of shell words and the exact strings in the command.  [Shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) doesn't have any special syntax, but wraps the command in `sh -c`, and that shell handles all of the normal things you'd expect a shell to do.

Using `RUN` as an example:

```sh
# These are the same:
RUN ["ls", "-la", "some directory"]
RUN ls -la 'some directory'

# These are the same (and print a dollar sign):
RUN ["echo", "$FOO"]
RUN echo \$FOO

# These are the same (and a shell does variable expansion):
RUN echo $FOO
RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $FOO"]
```

If you have both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` this expansion happens separately for each half.  This is where the split you have causes trouble: none of these options will work:

```sh
# Docker doesn't expand variables at all in exec form
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["/usr/src/app/${CODEPATH}"]
# ["python3", "/usr/src/app/${CODEPATH}"] with no expansion

# The "sh -c" wrapper gets interpreted as an argument to Python
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD /usr/src/app/${CODEPATH}
# ["python3", "/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/src/app/${CODEPATH}"]

# "sh -c" only takes one argument and ignores the rest
ENTRYPOINT python3
CMD ["/usr/src/app/${CODEPATH}"]
# ["/bin/sh", "-c", "python3", ...]
```

The only real effect of this `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD` split is to make a container that can only run Python scripts, without special configuration (an awkward `docker run --entrypoint` option); you're still providing most of the command line in `CMD`, but not all of it.  I tend to recommend that the whole command go in `CMD`, and you reserve `ENTRYPOINT` for a couple of more specialized uses; there is also a pattern of putting the complete command in `ENTRYPOINT` and trying to use the `CMD` part to pass it options.  Either way, things will work better if you put the whole command in one directive or the other.